# Derby jpa select MAX()

Tags: jpa, derby

I have a little problem with my query.
Here my table [image: table]
And I want this rows
[image: rows]

But I only get one row
[image: rows]

Here my query :

```
        Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT OBJECT(historic) FROM Historic historic WHERE historic.user.id = :user_id AND historic.enchere.id = historic.enchere.id AND historic.limcoins = (SELECT MAX(historic.limcoins) FROM Historic historic WHERE historic.enchere.id = historic.enchere.id AND historic.state LIKE :state)");
        q.setParameter("user_id", user_id);
        q.setParameter("state", "none");
        List<Historic> list = q.getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found.

Replace the = oprator by IN

```
historic.limcoins IN (SELECT MAX(historic.limcoins) FROM Historic historic WHERE historic.enchere.id = historic.enchere.id AND historic.state LIKE :state)
```